# adding variables to component packaging file

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

During installation I want Joomla to fetch the component name from the language files. Actually I tried to do it in this way.

```
<extension type="component" version="2.5.0" method="upgrade">

<name>COM_MYGREATCOMPONENT_NAME</name> 
...
```

And in language file I have this:

```
COM_MYGREATCOMPONENT_NAME=Name of my great Component
```

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that is not possible.

You have to add the "com_name" name in that variable and it should not change for each language.

You can read more about this file here:

http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files